# How can I practice my SQL Server, Sybase, and Oracle skills on a linux box?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sybase

I have a linux box. When I had a Windows box, I was able to download the free non-commericial use MS SQL Server.

How can I run free personal copies of SQL Server, Sybase, or Oracle on my linux box?

I don't need to to have any permanent databases or any great amount of storage. I just want to (re-)familiarize myself with these different SQL dialects, and compare techniques and timing to the MySQL and postgresql I do have installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not run on Linux.  [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), however, would and likely came with your Linux distribution.

The Oracle download is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle11g/111060_linuxsoft.html).

Sybase is [here](http://www.sybase.com/linuxpromo).

Comment: Also available for 64-bit Linux:  http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle11g/111060_linx8664soft.html

Comment: both links need to be refreshed

Answer (score 3):

At least for Oracle, they have their [Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html), which is  free download and available for Linux.

For SQL Server, you will have to get Windows, either as a separate OS, or in a virtual machine (like Virtual Box or VMWare).

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer as it was a bit more comprehensive, but I upmodded yours.

Comment: If it is for self-educational purposes you can download all Oracle software, not just the Express Edition.

Comment: Unless you want to practice Oracle installation or administration, you should get Express Edition, though. It is so much easier to install and manage.

Comment: Unless you want to explore the new Oracle 11 features.

Comment: <speculation>11gR2 will come in june, so 11XE will come early 2010</speculation>.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xen or VMWare to create a new virtual machine running Windows or whatever platform you fancy.

If you set the VM to full screen it is pretty much like running natively. Alternatively, connect to your virtual machines via a linux Remote Desktop/RDP client.

If you have a student ID, you can get Windows Server 2003 & 2008 + SQL Server 2005 & 2008 + VS 2005 & 2008 + a bunch of other goodies for free via Microsoft Dreamspark --- https://www.dreamspark.com/

Note that you can probably obtain a student ID by signing up for a random class (and then dropping it) at your local community college.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way to get started with Oracle**

- Get the free vmware player here:

  http://www.vmware.com/products/player/
- And the vmware oracle appliance here:

  http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/62414

Running this gets you an installed and configured server.  Download the (also free) client and developer tools and you're set.